# Get most common ip's from directory full of pcap to csv files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, ip

I have a directory full of very large csv files that were converted to csv from pcap.

I'm trying to iterate through each csv file in that directory and get the most common source IP addresses (column 2).

Currently my output is incorrect, because it seems that I've managed to have each file dump its values into the next file before starting.  Each file appears to have the same ip's, and I know that's not the case.

```
ipCounter = collections.Counter()

#iterate through all of the files in the directory, using glob
for filename in glob.glob('/path/to/directory/*'):
    with open(filename) as input_file:
        #skip column titles
        input_file.next()

        for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=','):
            ipCounter[row[2]] += 1

    print 'Source IPs most common in: %s' % filename
    print ipCounter.most_common()
```

I'm not exactly a pro with Python, so there may be a better way to do this, but this is what I've gotten so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks fine. If you want to do a per-file `most_common()` though you need to move your counter inside the for loop. Or have two counters, one giving you a per-file total, and second giving you an overall count for the whole folder:

```
import collections
import glob

ip_counter_all = collections.Counter()    

for filename in glob.glob('ip*.csv'):
    ip_counter = collections.Counter()

    with open(filename) as input_file:
        csv_input = csv.reader(input_file)
        header = next(csv_input)

        for row in csv_input:
            ip_counter[row[2]] += 1

    ip_counter_all.update(ip_counter)

    print '\nSource IPs most common in: {}'.format(filename)

    for ip_addr, count in ip_counter.most_common():
        print "  {}  {}".format(ip_addr, count)

print '\nOverall IPs most common:'

for ip_addr, count in ip_counter_all.most_common():
    print "  {}  {}".format(ip_addr, count)
```

Which would give you output such as:

```
Source IPs most common in: ips.csv
  1.1.1.1  2
  1.2.3.4  1
  1.4.2.3  1

Source IPs most common in: ips2.csv
  1.1.1.1  2
  1.2.3.4  1
  1.4.2.3  1

Overall IPs most common:
  1.1.1.1  4
  1.2.3.4  2
  1.4.2.3  2
```

You could also use the newer [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=format%20mini#format-specification-mini-language) method of displaying your strings.